# How to retrieve the UID of a document inserted into a FireStore collection from my Angular code using Angular Fire?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am working on an Angular 9 project using AngularFire to interact with FireStore databse.

I have this code snippet that correctly perform an insert on a collection of my FireStore database, it works fine:

```
this.db
        .collection("calendar")
        .add({ title: newEvent.title,
               start: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(newEvent.start),
               end: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(newEvent.end)
             })
        .then(function() {
          console.log(" event successfully written!");
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.error("Error writing document event: ", error);
        });
```

I only have a problem. I want to retrieve the document **UID** related to the inserted document. I think that I have to implement this behavior into the function defined into the **then()** operator (I am not totally sure of this assertion) but how? I am not understanding what is the correct way to implement this behavior and maybe I am missing something.

How can I retrieve the UID of the new document inserted by this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`add()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference?authuser=0#add) method returns "a Promise resolved with a [`DocumentReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) pointing to the newly created document after it has been written to the backend."

So, the following should do the trick:

```
this.db
        .collection("calendar")
        .add({ title: newEvent.title,
               start: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(newEvent.start),
               end: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(newEvent.end)
             })
        .then(function(docRef) {    // <-----
          const docID = docRef.id;  // <-----
          console.log(" event successfully written!");
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.error("Error writing document event: ", error);
        });
```

Comment: FYI the AngularFire API isn't exactly the same as the plain JavaScript API.  We actually don't know for sure which one is in use here.  AF wraps pretty much everything into its own types.  See: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#adding-documents-to-a-collection

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out @DougStevenson. Can't we deduce from the [library implementation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/7cb6c03481af7a7cf2063b1fcc6b37b1c657221b/src/firestore/collection/collection.ts#L137) that, in the case of `add()`, it will behave the same way than the JavaScript SDK?

Comment: I don't know.  I've never used it.

Comment: How about starting with `this.db.collection("calendar").doc()` recording the generated doc.id, then doing a set?

Comment: @danh That's also a possible approach indeed. IMHO one would use this approach when he wants to generate a docRef (and thus a doc ID) to be used before he actually creates the doc, e.g. to set a listener to a to-be-created document or to use the docId in a batched write in order to create, at the same time, another doc with the same docId (in another collection).